# Group data using Google Sheets Query function

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have the following data in a Google Sheet:

[image: Data]

I want to run the Query function in another sheet so that when a date is selected the Query will return all attendees who attended an event on a single date in one column like this:

[image: After Query]

My formula only returns one Attendee under each date when there could be 50 staff attending one event. I want all 50 in one column rather than 50 separate columns.

Below is a link to my data. Cell D2 of the 'Other Attendances' sheet is my Query function.

[Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11LUeT9z9bR98UBXn68nu22YlTHhdI0ASuZa9M8b9u_U/edit?usp=sharing)

I would appreciate help with a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE({QUERY('Form Responses 4'!B:D,
 "select B,C 
  where C >= date '"&TEXT(B5, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and C <= date '"&TEXT(B6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and B = '"&B4&"' 
  order by C asc", 1), 
 REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(QUERY('Form Responses 4'!B:D,
 "select D
  where C >= date '"&TEXT(B5, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and C <= date '"&TEXT(B6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and B = '"&B4&"' 
  order by C asc", 1), ";"), "^, ", )}))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE({QUERY('Form Responses 4'!B:D,
 "select B,C 
  where C >= date '"&TEXT(B5, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and C <= date '"&TEXT(B6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and B = '"&B4&"'"&
    IF(B3<>"all", "and D contains '"&B3&"'", )&" 
  order by C asc", 1), 
 REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(QUERY('Form Responses 4'!B:D,
 "select D
  where C >= date '"&TEXT(B5, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and C <= date '"&TEXT(B6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and B = '"&B4&"'"&
    IF(B3<>"all", "and D contains '"&B3&"'", )&" 
  order by C asc", 1), ";"), "^, ", )}))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE({QUERY('Form Responses 4'!B:D,
 "select B,C 
  where C >= date '"&TEXT(B5, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and C <= date '"&TEXT(B6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"& 
    IF(B4<>"all", "and B = '"&B4&"'", )&
    IF(B3<>"all", "and D contains '"&B3&"'", )&" 
  order by C asc", 1), 
 REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(QUERY('Form Responses 4'!B:D,
 "select D
  where C >= date '"&TEXT(B5, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and C <= date '"&TEXT(B6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"& 
    IF(B4<>"all", "and B = '"&B4&"'", )&
    IF(B3<>"all", "and D contains '"&B3&"'", )&" 
  order by C asc", 1), ";"), "^, ", )}))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. Works well when selecting all Attendees but doesn't work if you select one Attendee. I see that you changed the source data from Form Responses 4! A:C rather than E:F

Comment: did you even try the 2nd formula?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't see that. That's perfect - thank you very much

Comment: I have now noticed that the "all" function doesn't work for the Event Attended dropdown.